# Basic Authentication on MS Edge using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, basic-authentication, microsoft-edge

Does anyone have a good way to do basic auth on Edge?  I have tried https://user:pass@mysite.com, but MS hasn't liked that in a long time.  I tried using `alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(user, pass));` a la IE, but the Edge auth pop-up isn't registering as an alert.  Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish there was a better way, but I solved this by using [Robotil](http://codoid.com/robotil/). It's a wrapper for the Java Robot class that let's you execute Robot commands on a remote host.  It works as well as the Robot solution would work.  Cheers.